# Query Custom Apps

Tags: soql, custom, app

I would like to query an object that would return the "Created by" date from all custom apps in my org. Is there a way to do this through SOQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`AppMenuItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm) object. You can filter by `Type` to get just the "apps" that you see in the menu:

```
SELECT ApplicationId, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name FROM AppMenuItem WHERE Type = 'TabSet'
```